# How do I keep frequently accessed folders from appearing in Quick Access?

Tags: windows-10

`Quick Access` is a section that pops out every time you open the `File Explorer`. It's quite helpful, to be honest. As it provides links to your favorite files and directories in the OS.

That said, it could get messy real quick while you're using your PC. As an example, here's mine after using it just over a couple of days:

[image]

I'd rather have a "favorite" screen like the one that was on Windows 7. I want to keep stuff that actually matters for me there instead of the things I accessed recently.

Is there any possible way to make it behave that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent folders from appearing in the Quick Access section, go to View - Options in any File Explorer window and uncheck the box that says "**Show recently accessed folders in Quick access**". You can do the same for files and also change the starting view when you open File Explorer from Quick access to This PC.

Here is a screenshot of the **Folder options** dialog to highlight the settings I mentioned:

[image]

The screenshot shows text in Spanish but the settings are pretty straightforward.